# Custom Action View layout not responding to menu item lisetener

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have created one custom action view layout using `MenuItemCompat` Java code is as shown in code below :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem shoppingCartitem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_action_item_id);
        shoppingCartitem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
Log.v("MyAPP", "Listener called");
                return true;
            }
        });
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(shoppingCartitem, R.layout.my_custom_action_view_layout);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

menu_main.xml as follows :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_action_item_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="9999"
        android:title="@string/menu"
        myapp:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

What am I missing here, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener)):

> Set a custom listener for invocation of this menu item. In most situations, it is more efficient and easier to use onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) or onContextItemSelected(MenuItem).

So you can simply override the `onOptionsItemSelected` callback, which is easier.

By the way to me your code seems to be right, but it doesn't do anything. Have you tried doing something like `Log.v("MyAPP", "Listener called");` inside it?

### EDIT:

I wrote this code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_action_item_id);
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Log.v("MyApp", "Inside listener");
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.main_activity);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

}
```

main_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_action_item_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="9999"
        android:title="Menu"
        myapp:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

And this is the result of the LogCat (I clicked the icon twice):

[image: LogCat]

As you can see it works without problems

Comment: I have checked with debugger debug doesn't stop within listener on clicking that item, also I tried by putting the logs as you are saying doesn't work.

Comment: thanx, I have just one question here, In line MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.main_activity); don't you think you should use some other customized layout than activities layout ?

Comment: Yes, you definitely should! But I created a quick sample app, and I re-used the same layout to save time :)

Comment: This is still not working for me.Do you have any idea or suggestions that what else i can recheck here? I am testing on Jelly Bean(4.1.2) API level 16.

Answer (score -1):

please try

> MenuItem shoppingCartitem = menu.findItem(R.id.my_action_item_id);

change to

> MenuItem shoppingCartitem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.my_action_item_id);